# preg_replace integer in a string with one value higher

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Say if I have a string that's like

```
    $string = 'list12345678';
```

I want it to return a new string that's 12345679

So preg_replace a number that's in a string with one digit up from the defined string.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()`

Answer (score 1):

This is really trivial, once you know the things you need.

Namely, the function you require is [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback).

Your regex must capture one or more digits.

Your callback must return that captured number, with 1 added to it.

Done.

Write some code, and let me know if you have further problems ;)

Comment: I've never used this function before, so I am kind of lost. Plus I haven't coded in PHP in a while so I am a bit rusty.

My code is as follows:

The string I am working with is currently "list37151.html"

I use this code:

$url = $_GET['url'];

function new_number($matches)
{
  // as usual: $matches[0] is the complete match
  // $matches[1] the match for the first subpattern
  // enclosed in '(...)' and so on
  return $matches[1].($matches[2]+1);
}

echo preg_replace_callback(
            "|(\d/)|",
            "new_number",
            $url);

All that does is add a "1" to the first number.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked. You should be able to understand from the examples given.

Comment: Well time to go and read up on the function in the manual then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`$s = 'list12345678.html';`

```
function n($matches) {
  return $matches[1]+1;
}

print_r(preg_replace_callback('/[^1-9]+(\d+).*$/','n',$s));
```